# issue using HorizontalPicker library

Tags: java, android

[image]i implemented [this library](https://github.com/blazsolar/HorizontalPicker) into my app for accomplishing a horizontal picker view i think i followed properly whatever it asked for but i dont know why its nit showing anything (widget is here but its totally transparent) this is how i implemented this :

mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="pb.monthpicker.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">



<com.wefika.horizontalpicker.HorizontalPicker
        xmlns:picker="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.wefika.horizontalpicker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
        android:ellipsize="start"

        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="-1"
        android:id="@+id/month_picker"
        picker:values="@array/values"
        picker:dividerSize="@dimen/itemPadding"
        picker:sideItems="@integer/sideItems"

        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this are the values:

```
// value of sideItems
  `<integer name="sideItems">3</integer>`

// value of text size:
        <dimen name="textSize">16dp</dimen>
//value of padding:
    <dimen name="itemPadding">8dp</dimen>

// value of array
        <string-array name="values">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
        <item>6</item>
        <item>7</item>
        <item>8</item>
        <item>9</item>
        <item>10</item>
    </string-array>
```

// build.grade

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "pb.monthpicker"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
 }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.wefika:horizontal-picker:+'
}
```

guys any idea what am doing wrong ? any guidance will be so helpful for me , thanks :)

Comment: Please double check the title of the question, wouldn't it be better "Problem using HorizontalPicker library"? Not implanting for sure.

Comment: show your gradle file.

Comment: @SuhasB please check my updated question

Comment: @remyboys see answer bellow.

Comment: @SuhasB am implementing this on a new blank project (the demo which is provided by android studio when we create a new project ) so which part's full code you want ? the mainActivity ? or Main.xml or build.gradle ?

Comment: also post the screen shot of your present view.

Comment: @SuhasB see the updated question , and present view ? you mean while running it or the view of xml ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101763/discussion-between-suhas-b-and-remy-boys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace in your gradle file

```
compile 'com.wefika:horizontal-picker:+
```

with

```
compile 'com.wefika:horizontal-picker:1.1.0'
```

Try with this layout :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.wefika.horizontalpicker.example.MainActivity">

        <com.wefika.horizontalpicker.HorizontalPicker
        android:id="@+id/picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="2"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:values="@array/values"
        app:dividerSize="10dp"
        app:sideItems="1"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: still  the output is same :(

Comment: 01-27 16:09:11.283 6218-6218/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: pb.monthpicker, PID: 6218
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pb.monthpicker/pb.monthpicker.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.wefika.horizontalpicker.HorizontalPicker

Comment: you know what it means ?

Comment: which is line number 13 in xml ?  android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" line for    android:textColor="@android:colorPrimaryDark"

Comment: bellow you question  comment there " 
Let us continue this discussion in chat." click on that.

Comment: Click here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101763/discussion-between-suhas-b-and-remy-boys